# Grub rescure: ошибка при удалении boot sdb

Tags: linux

Купила новый ноут hp и хотела поставить lmde betsy. Однако столкнулась с проблемой: можно поставить только 4 главных раздела, а у меня уже стояли hp мануал в sda1 и boot в  sdb. Удалила оба раздела. В итоге не смогла завершить инсталляцию betsy, а при загрузке компьютера появилась ошибка boot rescure. После команды ls выходит почему то один hd0. Как снова сделать погрузчик, помогите, плз!

Comment: Всё правильно. Основных раздела может быть не более четырёх. Сделайте один из них логическим - и вот уже его делите хоть на двадцать четыре. Решение: запускайте заново установку ОС и правильно размечайте диск.

Comment: Спасибо, а что делать, если уже убила все разделы,  остался один unnalocated на dev/sda. И как мне запустить теперь компьютер, если выходит ошибка grub rescure.

Comment: Все так же - установить систему заново

Comment: Да я делала это уже несколько раз. Открывается рабочий стол с иконкой linux install. Жму на него и пытаюсь установить вот по этой инструкции https://youtu.be/cW0T-q72Fd0 и выдается ошибка. Я думала, что это потому что я удалила погрузчик и теперь не знаю, как его назад вернуть. Диск

Comment: Установочная флэшка с uefi  и жесткий диск ssd